# How to separate ul list when it is not empty

Tags: html, css

I have created a to do list which is used by typing in the input field and clicking the plus button. When you click the tick next to the list item, it transfers from the ul list with the id of to-do, to another ul list with the id of completed which you will see in the html file. I want a line to appear above the #completed list only when a list item has been transferred there, so as to show a separation between the first to-do list and the second list of completed items. I tried using:

```
ul.to-do#completed:not(:empty):before{
content: '';
width: 150px;
height: 0.7px;
background: black;
position: absolute;
}
```

to make the line appear when the ul list is not empty, thus only when you click the tick button on at least one list item, but the line is showing even before any list items have been created. Is  there anyone smart enough to solve this? Can't find on the internet.

```js
var completeSVG =
  '<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 52 52" style="enable-background:new 0 0 52 52;" xml:space="preserve"> <g> <path d="M38.252,15.336l-15.369,17.29l-9.259-7.407c-0.43-0.345-1.061-0.274-1.405,0.156c-0.345,0.432-0.275,1.061,0.156,1.406 l10,8C22.559,34.928,22.78,35,23,35c0.276,0,0.551-0.114,0.748-0.336l16-18c0.367-0.412,0.33-1.045-0.083-1.411 C39.251,14.885,38.62,14.922,38.252,15.336z"/> </svg>';
var removeSVG =
  '<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" id="removeB" class="removeB" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 328.51 328.51" style="enable-background:new 0 0 328.51 328.51;" xml:space="preserve"> <polygon points="229.044,88.858 164.255,153.647 99.466,88.858 88.858,99.466 153.647,164.255 88.858,229.044 99.466,239.651 164.255,174.862 229.044,239.651 239.651,229.044 174.862,164.255 239.651,99.466   "/> </svg>';

 /*var button = document.querySelector(".complete");
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        this.classList.toggle("clicked");
    });*/

function removeItem() {
  var item = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  item.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
}

function completeItem() {
  var completeitem = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  var completeparent = completeitem.parentNode;

  var id = completeparent.id;

  var target = (id === "to-do")
    ? document.getElementById("completed")
    : document.getElementById("to-do");

  completeparent.removeChild(completeitem);
  target.prepend(completeitem);
}

document.getElementById("button-plus").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var value = document.getElementById("input").value;
  if (value) {
    addItem(value);
    document.getElementById("input").value = "";
  }
});
function addItem(text) {
  var list = document.getElementById("to-do");

  item = document.createElement("li");
  item.innerText = text;
  var buttons = document.createElement("div");
  buttons.classList.add("buttons");

  var remove = document.createElement("button");
  remove.classList.add("remove");
  remove.innerHTML = removeSVG;
  remove.addEventListener("click", removeItem);

  var complete = document.createElement("button");
  complete.classList.add("complete");
  complete.innerHTML = completeSVG;
  complete.addEventListener("click", completeItem);
  complete.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.classList.toggle('clicked');
  });

  buttons.appendChild(remove);
  buttons.appendChild(complete);
  item.appendChild(buttons);

 
  
  list.prepend(item);
  
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: rgb(162, 193, 60);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(159, 160, 155);
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

header input {
 appearance: none;
 text-indent: 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
 border-top-right-radius: 25px;
 border-top-left-radius: 12px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
 width: 100%;
 background: rgb(233, 255, 170);
 height: 45px;
 font-family: Century Gothic;
 border: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding-right: 60px;
}

header button {
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
top: 13.5px;
height: 43px;
width: 50px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
border-top-right-radius: 25px;
appearance: none;
border: none;
background: rgb(238, 255, 173);
border-left: 2px solid rgb(162, 193, 60);
cursor: pointer;
}

button svg {
z-index: 6;
position: absolute;
border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
border-top-right-radius: 25px;
right: 0;
top: -1px;
}/*
.container{
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}*/
 .to-do {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 0;
  /*border: 1px lid black;*/
}
.to-do li{
  width: 85%;
  background: rgb(233, 255, 170);
  min-height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  padding: 0 105px 0 25px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
}
.to-do li .buttons{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: white;
}
.to-do li .buttons button{
  appearance: none;
  width: 47.5px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(233, 255, 170);
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.to-do li .buttons button:last-of-type:before{
  content: '';
  width: 0.8px;
  height: 29px;
  background: gray;
  opacity: 0.4;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -6px;
}/*
.to-do li button:nth-child(1):hover .x-fill{
  fill: red;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.to-do li button:nth-child(2):hover .tick-fill{
  fill: orange;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}*/
.complete svg{
  fill: gray;
}
.complete svg:hover{
  fill: green;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.complete.clicked svg{
  fill: green;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.remove svg{
  fill: gray;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.remove svg:hover{
  fill: red;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
ul.to-do#completed:not(:empty){
  position: relative;
}

ul.to-do#completed:not(:empty):before{
  content: '';
  width: 150px;
  height: 0.7px;
    background: black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<head>

<title>To do List App</title>

</head>
<body>
<header>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Next on my to do list is....." id="input">
  <button id="button-plus">
 <svg width="48" height="43" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect fill="#0186b2" height="28" id="svg_1" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="5" width="4" x="19.5" y="8.5"/>
  <rect fill="#47bcbc" height="3" id="svg_2" stroke="#000000" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="5" width="28" x="7.5" y="20.5"/>
</svg>
   
    </svg>
  </button>
</header>
  <div class="container">
<ul id="to-do" class="to-do">
  </ul>
    <ul id="completed" class="to-do">
 </ul>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#completed` isn't empty; it contains a text node with a line break followed by a space. In the future, that won't matter:

> The :empty pseudo-class represents an element that has no children except, optionally, document white space characters.
>   [...]
>   Note: In Level 2 and Level 3 of Selectors, :empty did not match elements that contained only white space. This was changed so that that—given white space is largely collapsible in HTML and is therefore used for source code formatting, and especially because elements with omitted end tags are likely to absorb such white space into their DOM text contents—elements which authors perceive of as empty can be selected by this selector, as they expect.
>
> —[CSS Selectors Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-empty-pseudo)

But for now, remove the whitespace from `#completed`:

```
<ul id="completed" class="to-do"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a statement to the `completeItem()` function which adds a class dynamically?

For instance, at the bottom of `completeItem()`, you can include the line:

```
target.classList.add('is-populated');
```

And then your corresponding CSS selector (instead of `ul.to-do#completed:not(:empty)::before`) will be:

```
ul.to-do#completed.is-populated::before
```